# Check if a given location (lat, lng) is within a city area without calling to Google Map API

Tags: location, geocoding

We are doing location aware projects for some Major Cities in US (eg, NY, Chicago, LA). In any given second,  close to 50-60 requests coming to our server, each with user's current location, if user's location is within the city we supported, we wants to return different result.

Currently we are using Google Map GeoCoding to determine if a given location is within City, and cache those result in our DB, and I know this is not optimal.

Is there any open data I can get to help us determine a City boundary, and we can simply use programming logic to check if a given location is within the City boundary.

Thanks
James

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to have an in-house solution, thus no third-party API calls, you always have the option of extending your current database to be spatial "aware". For PostgreSQL (for example) this would undoubtedly be PostGIS.

A rough go-about in PostgreSQL would be to capture your cities of interest into separate, 2D WKT (Well-Known Text) polygon objects. You should create a table with a geometry column containing all these polygons, preferably with an SRID of 4326.

The next step is to find out in which polygon a given user point (lat/lng) lies. For this you can make use of the Simple Features function `ST_Intersects` to determine whether or not a given lat/lng coordinate is within a certain polygon.

In PostgreSQL/PostGIS such a query would look similar to this:

```sql
SELECT city_name 
  FROM our_cities
  WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.169113 135.154678)', 4326), city_geom);
```

Here I select the name of the city from a table called `our_cities`. This table holds the geometrical data together with other attributes, such as the city name. The `WHERE` clause contains the actual spatial lookup using the `ST_Intersects` function.

I convert a given lat/lng coordinate into geometry first, using another Simple Features function called `ST_GeomFromText`, which I feed a POINT object and the correct `SRID`. Next I compare this with a column called `city_geom`, which is the actual polygon geometry from your `our_cities` table.

The only hard part here is indeed to capture polygons of a high enough resolution (point count) to use in your spatial lookups. Some cities do offer boundary information as open data, but a possible caveat could be that this information is in a so-called UTM projection (instead of the basic Mercator one). UTM is a more localized projection and produces more accurate results. But that deserves its own topic all together.

Most spatial extensions for other databases such as MySQL (MariaDB) or Oracle should adhere to the same spatial standards (WKT/WKB/Simple Features/...) and thus should use the same spatial objects and function names.

Edit: After some research, you could obtain fairly detailed data from sources like [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) or [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/) as stated in answers such as [these](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/are-there-any-free-administrative-boundaries-available-as-shapefiles). Keep in mind that most of these data sources may not always be used for commercial purposes. You could also buy more detailed data at sites such as [Map Technica](http://www.maptechnica.com/us-county-boundary-and-geodata) or you could take a look at [Tiger](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html) data, from the US government itself.